# Add new filter to Map function in couchbase

Tags: json, mapreduce, couchbase

I have documents stored in couchbase in the following format:

```
{
"id" : 1,
"type" : "queueStat",
"timestampIN" : 1524131000000,
"timestampOut" : 1524131925000
}
```

I have a queue, timestamp IN & OUT get updated when entering and leaving the queue.

The Map function is :

```
function (doc, meta) {
    if (doc.id && doc.type && doc.type === "queueStat" ){
        emit([doc.id, doc.timestampIN]);
    }
}
```

My used query has a StartKey and an EndKey, which are based on document ID and the timestamp IN.

This works really fine, now I want to add a new filter based on the time spent in the queue. I did the following changes:

The map:

```
  function (doc, meta) {
        if (doc.id && doc.type && doc.type === "queueStat" ){
            emit([doc.id, doc.timestampIN, doc.timestampOUT-doc.timestampIN]);
        }
    }
```

When calling this new Map function, with for example:

```
http://192.168.1.41:8092/default/_design/queue/_view/CalculateDiff?stale=false&startkey=["1", 1524131000000, 0]&endkey=["1", 1524131925000, 0]
```

it does not take my 3rd added filter in consideration :(

Comment: It looks like your function is expected a field called `timestampOUT` but the field in your document is called `timestampOut` (notice the different casing). Could that be the issue?

Comment: timestampOut is just an example, the question is: should all my filters be keys of my json document?

Comment: Have you examined the raw map output in the web UI to check that the `doc.timestampOUT - doc.timestampIN` expression is working correctly? I.e. producing the kind of numbers you expect?